# How to deploy a service into some selective nodes in Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a swarm cluster having 3 worker nodes (**node1**, **node2** & **node3**) and two services (**service1** & **service2**). Anyway, **service1** needs to be deployed in **node1** and **node2** whereas **service2** needs to be deployed into **node2** and **node3**. However, the `deploy.placement.constraints` is OK with 1 node. In my scenario, I made the following **compose.yml** file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  service1: 
    image: IMAGE1
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure 
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.id==<node1_ID>
          - node.id==<node2_ID>
  service2: 
    image: IMAGE2
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure 
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.id==<node2_ID>
          - node.id==<node3_ID>
```

No services deployed into any node for the above **compose.yml**. If I comment out one of the node.id in `deploy.placement.constraints` services deployed into the defined nodes (i.e., constraints can take a single `node.id`).

- **How can I deploy services into the multiple nodes with `deploy.placement.constraints` rather than one?**

**UPDATE: It can be done by adding a label into nodes. However, I am looking for an approach not adding a label into nodes manually. Any alternative/suggestion?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Label the nodes appropriately for each service and then use a single placement constraint. Placement constraints are logically ANDed with each other which makes anything complex somewhat difficult.

```bash
docker node update node1 --label-add service1=true
docker node update node2 --label-add service1=true
docker node update node2 --label-add service2=true
docker node update node3 --label-add service2=true
```

```yaml
services:
  service1:
    ...
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.labels.service1==true
  service2:
    ...
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.labels.service2==true
```

Comment: any other alternative approach without adding a label into nodes?

Comment: No. With no way to write complex constraints you need to build "or" conditions with creative use of labels.